# Javascript Always Parse Null Values to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a problem to parse data from JavaScript to MVC Controller using JQuery AJAX Method

Below here is my Javascript code with Post Method to MVC Controller

```
function EmailSend(templateID) {
   var EmailAttr = new Object();
     EmailAttr.templateID = "d-bdc3d9aef71d418780c9a3c2c9521225";
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Home/SendEmail/",
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify( EmailAttr ),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",  
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
          }
        });
}
```

And this is the MVC Controller that I used

```
 [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail(EmailAttr emailAttr)
  {
    var result = await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(emailAttr.templateID);
    return Json(emailAttr);
  }
```

And this is the result if I checked the emailAttr.templateID value
result with debugger: [image]

I already try to tweak around ajax POST method in the part of data, contentType, dataType, and etc.

I am expecting that I will get value in emailAttr.templateID.

Thank you for your help BTW

Comment: All your "success" handler does is log the result returned from the ajax call. It makes no attempt to update the `EmailAttr.templateID` value or anything else.

Comment: You are sending a string, but are expecting it to be json. Try updating your data to be `data: EmailAttr`

Comment: @Pointy my success handler right now only try to get the return result from the controller, I changed it a bit to check if the return is correct or not

Comment: @peinearydevelopment did that but the value is still null, is there any specific method to parse controller with async task?

Comment: OK, I see now.  Well you can use your browser "Network" debugging tool to see what the outgoing ajax request actually looks like. That might be helpful.

Comment: @Pointy any hint, which of these params that I need to check in "Network"

Comment: Well just make sure that the way the HTTP "Request" looks is what you expect it to look like. Is the POST body the JSON that you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, this is the code that I add in javascript to ensure that it will work

```
function EmailSend(templateID) {
var EmailAttr = new Object();
EmailAttr.templateID = templateID;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Home/SendEmail/",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: EmailAttr,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })};
```

It seems that I need to change content type from

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

to

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```